# background images one after another, how?

Tags: css

I'm trying to use different background images one after another horizontally using the code below but only the last image is coming out.

```
.wallP{background-image:url(images/arc.png) centre left,
url(images/bg_st.png);
background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
```

Comment: If that is how it's written in your css, I'm surprised anything gets shown at all. You can have a [comman-separated list](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-image) of `url(..)`s as the value of the background-image property.

Comment: the only thing i am getting  now is one on another but i'd like them to be one after another horizontally such as wallpaper.

Answer (score 0):

You can only have 1 background image per element.

You could mix them all together and have a sprite that shows it.

Or, create different elements:

```
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
<div id="three"></div>
```

and then give them all seperate backgrounds:

```
#one{
    background:url(images/arc.png);
}
#two{
    background:url(images/bg_st);
}
#three{
    background:#0f0f0f;
}
```

Also, whatever code you posted, it is not going to display. There are various errors in it:

```
background-image:background-image:url
                ^ only need the one background-image

url(images/bg_st.png;
                   ^ missing a ')'
```